# mssql_connect on Linux server with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I know that mssql_connect will not work on windows server with PHP 5.3 or later, but will it work on Linux?

Comment: See the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php if it says "won't work on Windows", you can safely assume that it will work on all other platforms that PHP supports.

Answer (score 0):

mssql_connect = Connect to a MS SQL Server

mysql_connect = Connect to a MySQL Server (open source database server) usually on linux

You can get MySQL on windows platforms